# Skyrim, short term storage in random container

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In know in general for long term storage putting stuff in random containers isn't good because a lot of them reset, but how long could you keep stuff in one? I'm about to do the Thalmor Embassy quest, and was wondering if I could just stash some stuff in one just while I complete it. I know that poor wood elf probably won't want to smuggle in my 5 million potions I've amassed. (idk, maybe he would, but I do kind of want to role play and do it just bringing in a few things.)

Also, if I have my follower wait someplace nearby, will the quest be over fast enough that they'll still be there when I get back?

Comment: Delphine will take whatever you don’t give to the elf. You don’t need to toss your stuff into a random barrel.

Comment: Oh ok, that's good to know. I have.... an excessive amount of stuff so that's good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Safe Containers**

Some random containers are safe, some aren't. Certain container types (distinguished by the readable name when looking at the container) are set to never respawn, regardless of their location. The Elder Scrolls Pages has an article on these [Safe Containers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Containers#Safe_Containers).

That page has additional details and pictures of each container. They include:

- Child's Chest
- Noble Coffin
- Burial Coffin
- Common Cupboard
- Upper-Class Cupboard
- Noble Cupboard
- Common Dresser
- Upper-Class Dresser
- Orc Dresser
- Common End Table
- Upper-Class End Table
- Noble End Table
- Orc End Table
- Pot
- Riekling Hut
- Sack (not Large Sack or Small Sack)
- Strongbox (not Strong Box)
- Safe
- Noble Wardrobe

**Safe Locations**

There are also [Safe Locations](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Safe) that never respawn, meaning that none of the containers in the location will respawn, regardless of their type. This includes player houses, as well as many other locations.

**Diplomatic Immunity**

However, none of this matters for your immediate problem.

Delphine will take all the stuff you didn't give to Malborn before you go inside, and give it back to you after you're done. As stated on [the Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Diplomatic_Immunity):

> There is only one chance to give him [Malborn] gear. Nothing else can be given to him once the trade dialogue closes, and remember nothing else can be taken inside; give it to Malborn. Give him some lockpicks, since there will be locks to pick.or just favor your items and you can still equip them even if there not in your inventory.
>
> Afterwards, the Dragonborn will meet with Delphine at the Solitude Stables at Katla's Farm to pick up the invitation and party disguise, and then drop off everything else on hand with Delphine; everything given to her will be stored safely until reclaimed after the mission. Delphine will store the inventory in a chest in her hidden office in the Sleeping Giant Inn, in Riverwood.

Comment: 'Orc' is a safe place to leave items? I'd expect them to wander off with the stuff.

Comment: @IG_42 "Orc dresser" is a safe place to leave things.

Answer (score 5):

## How long can I store my stuff in random containers?

It would take a week in game time until the unowned containers would reset. It's recommended that you don't store items in random containers at all.

## When my followers if waiting, how fast will the quest be enough that my followers is still waiting?

"Diplomatic Immunity" could be finished in a few minutes if you could find a way to complete it, and if you wait a day (in game), he/she will leave your service. Don't worry, the quest won't take those amount of days to finish.

Comment: ... are you talking in real time or game time?

Comment: @Timelord64 in game time for days

Comment: I think NPCs can take stuff from random containers, so they might steal some food. No idea if they also grab potions.

Comment: @Ids I haven't seen NPCs take stuff from random containers. I don't think so. The cells just reset which is why the random containers will no longer have your loot. Waste of items and gold.