# Is there a specific difference for "dwellings" in terms of storage, and if so, what is it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

From experience (in-game, and through discussion), it is generally advised *not* to store gear/treasure in a random barrel in a cave, because

1. Obviously because you can easily lose where that barrel was
2. More specifically, because the game can "reset" in that area, and delete your stash.

Is there actually any evidence that can be found to prove this (other than just situational), so I know where I can/cannot set up a "base". I.e. is there anything in the code (or elsewhere) that might indicate the difference between "Breezehome", an Inn, or a random cave?

Comment: I think we already have a question about Skyrim, asking where it's safe to store your stuff.  But, this is much less broad, so that's good.  May want to edit the question a bit more to focus on the specifics, too.

Comment: Related: [Aside from containers in bought houses or guilds/organizations, are there other 'safe' containers which will store items permanently (won't reset)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36256), [Skyrim, short term storage in random container](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272324)

Comment: @amaranth I'm terrible at titles. I have difficulty paraphrasing, so if you have something that works better, please feel free to edit the title :)

Comment: The tag provides the context, so I just removed it from the title. As for the answer, I'm looking for something like that, but specifically in relation to dwellings (like Breezehome for example), in contrast with everything else. Eg. "you can look for (variable) tied to each dwelling/container"

Comment: The difference wouldn't be the container itself but the area it is in. The same thing that tells enemies to respawn probably tells containers to refill themselves as well.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I was thinking there would be exactly something like that, which appears to be what amaranth is referring to.

Comment: @amaranth I checked the linked posts and the answers are just terrible.  There are outright incorrect and **unsafe** areas with 10+ votes.  [UESP link](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Safe) is a good place to start.

Comment: You've got answers [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121584/108003) and [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272412/108003), listing safe areas (regardless of container) and safe container types (regardless of area).

Comment: @DCShannon Glad you added that. I completely forgot that there are some locations that don't reset anything (including containers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Skyrim, there are two types of cells: cells that reset, and cells that are "safe" (don't reset). Whether a cell resets is based on the [EncounterZone](http://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Encounter_Zone) set in the cell's properties. When a cell resets, most things will respawn themselves -- including containers. If a container does not have the `respawn` flag set during the cell reset, its contents will be unchanged.

The designers generally made "dwellings" cells that don't reset (i.e. the cell's `EncounterZone` has the "Never Resets" flag set to `true`), but there are some exceptions. For "dwellings" that *do* reset, it seems that the devs tried to set the `respawn` flags to all containers in the cell to `false`, but there are definitely some oversights.

To find cells that never reset in the Creation Kit, browse the *Encounter Zones* in the Object Window (found in the *WorldData* section), and sort by *Never Resets*. For each encounter zone that you see where *Never Resets* has a value of *Y*, view the Use Info, and sort by *Type*. This will list all the cells that use this encounter zone.
[image: Encounter Zone Use Report]

To find places that reset, but have lots of non-respawning containers with the Creation Kit, one can look through the container items, sort by whether they respawn, then look at the Use Count for those containers. Oftentimes, you'll see that a container is used multiple times in one location. For instance, just now, I found that all the coffins the Riften Mausoleum don't respawn. Nifty!

[image: Creation Kit Screenshot]

*Source: Long-time modder, worked on QA for Skyrim*